# SQL Server (T-SQL): Avoid call scalar function multiple times

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a stored procedure which does a `SELECT` to return some rows. Within the `SELECT`, I need to check a condition in order to return the correct value for some columns. This condition consists on a scalar function. All times scalar function is called with the same parameter for the row being processed, see below:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    Name,
    Surname,
    CASE WHEN (dbo.GetNumTravels(Id) >= 50)
        THEN 10
        ELSE 99
    END as Factor1,
    CASE WHEN (dbo.GetNumTravels(Id) >= 50)
        THEN 15
        ELSE -1
    END as Factor2,
    CASE WHEN (dbo.GetNumTravels(Id) >= 50)
        THEN 30
        ELSE 70
    END as Factor3
FROM 
    Employees
WHERE 
    DepartmentId = 100
```

I am worried about performance, I mean, I do not like to call scalar function `dbo.GetNumTravels` multiples times, so how to avoid this and only call it once and then used it all the times I need it?

Comment: Why are you asking for this in the first place? What does `GetNumTravels` do and why is it slow? If you want to find each employee's travels you should be using joins or subqueries in the WHERE clause, *not* individual queries in the SELECT clause. You could use a *view* instead of a function and join it with `Employees`

Answer (score 3):

Scalar user defined functions are infamous for poor performance. If you can convert it to an inline table-valued function you can expect to see performance gains.

If you convert your scalar function to an inline table-valued function you can call it once for each row using `cross apply()` like so:

```
select
     Id,
     Name,
     Surname,
     case when x.NumTravels >= 50
        then 10
        else 99
     end as Factor1,
     case when x.NumTravels >= 50)
        then 15
        else -1
     end as Factor2,
     case when x.NumTravels >= 50
        then 30
        else 70
     end as Factor3
from Employees
  cross apply dbo.GetNumTravels_itvf(e.Id) x
where DepartmentId = 100
```

Reference:

- [When is a sql function not a function? "If it’s not inline, it’s rubbish." - Rob Farley](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2011/11/08/when-is-a-sql-function-not-a-function/)
- [Inline Scalar Functions - Itzik Ben-Gan](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/inline-scalar-functions)
- [Scalar functions, inlining, and performance: An entertaining title for a boring post - Adam Machanic](http://dataeducation.com/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post/)
- [tsql User-Defined Functions: Ten Questions You Were Too Shy To Ask - Robert Sheldon](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/tsql-user-defined-functions-ten-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/)

Comment: As a quick fix, if you do not want to convert your function from a scalar into a table-valued one, you can do "(SELECT dbo.SomeScalarFunc(a, b, c) as NumTravels) NumTravels" inside the FROM clause (or CROSS/OUTER APPLY). I do not know if this has any drawbacks in optimalization. Though it works and improved my query performance by limiting the number of function calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using derived table concept, In derived table we once called to function `dbo.GetNumTravels(Id)` only once and used its output in outer query, this may help to gaining performance at some level by avoiding multiple calls to same function.

```
SELECT 
       Id,
       Name,
       Surname,
       CASE WHEN (NumTravelsID >= 50)  THEN 10  ELSE 99 END as Factor1,
       CASE WHEN (NumTravelsID >= 50)  THEN 15  ELSE -1 END as Factor2,
       CASE WHEN (NumTravelsID >= 50)  THEN 30  ELSE 70 END as Factor3
FROM (
         SELECT
            Id,
            Name,
            Surname,
            dbo.GetNumTravels(Id) as NumTravelsID
         FROM Employees
         WHERE DepartmentId = 100  
 )M
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about performances (anyway, do your tests considering other answers too), but I would like to test this.  I tried to reduce use of function and use of CASE too.  Pls let me know

```
SELECT A.*
    , 10*F0+99*~F0 AS FACTOR1
    , 15*F0-1*~F0 AS FACTOR2
    , 30*F0+70*~F0 AS FACTOR3
FROM (
    SELECT
     Id,
     Name,
     Surname,
    CAST(CASE WHEN (dbo.GetNumTravels(Id) >= 50) THEN  1  ELSE 0 END AS BIT) AS F0     
    FROM Employees
    WHERE DepartmentId = 100
     ) A
```